# Deploy rails in production apache passenger ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, passenger, production

As I am deploying rails, I am getting the following error:

Web application could not be started

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
Error ID
312952ad
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `gem install bundler`

Comment: I tried.  error id changed to bee04163. I don't know if that reveals anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an installation issue.  I had to update the apache2 server config file for Ruby settings.  Now it works fine.